# Which are the Extreme Programming "core" practices?

Tags: agile, extreme-programming

Recently, I began reading about agile methodologies and XP in particular. I am a bit confused, though, about what are considered the practices involved in extreme programming.

More precisely:
Wikipedia reports 12 practices, which I someway believe to be the "classic" ones.

Both Kent Beck and Ron Jeffries indicate 13 practices (you can find the links at the bottom of wikipedia page about "Extreme Programming Practices", I cannot post them here since I am new user of Stack Overflow), while [this](http://xp123.com/xplor/xp0502/index.shtml) review of Kent Beck's "XP explained" (2nd edition) report more than 20 somewhat different practices.

As a complete beginner in the topic (and basically as a complete beginner as a programmer), I would like to be enlightened on the matter. My impression is that I should look at Beck's book, since the second edition has been written after several years of XPerience, but I can find a lot less material based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first edition of "XP explained", there was twelve practices.

In the second edition, the practices have been reorganized: some have been renamed or merged, some have been removed (Metaphor), and there now are: thirteen primary and eleven corollary practices.

Under the "First Edition Practices" topic in the page you mentioned, one can find the original list of twelve practices and how they appear in the update.

While reading, you'll certainly will people differentiating XP and XP2e (XP second edition).

Likely, there was four principles in the first edition and a fifth one (Respect) was introduced with the second edition.

Comment: I see. I still have one question, though, before I set the post as answered: in the review of XP2e I linked, more than 20 practiced are reported, but they are divided into 13 "primary" practices and 11 "corollary" practices; are the 13 "primary" ones those referred in Beck's and Jeffries' websites or I am missing something?

Comment: I didn't include the 11 corollary practices as they are not always applicable. They are listed as XP2e practices.

Comment: I'll mark the question as answered, though I am still quite perplexed: several practices in XP2e seem quite different from the "classic" ones. Today I bought the book, maybe it will make my mind clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained at  [Blog on Agile](https://manojgupta2000.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/agile-project-management-brief-introduction/) "https://manojgupta2000.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/agile-project-management-brief-introduction" , there are following methods

- Scrum:
- Crystal:
- Feature Driven Development:
- Lean Development:
- Dynamic Systems Development Methodology(DSDM):

Comment: These are just Agile "methods" (and, btw, you left out XP), my question was about practices in Extreme Programming (which is an Agile "method", using your reference terminology)